# Using Python setuptools with Sphinx and rst2pdf

Tags: python, pdf, python-sphinx, setuptools

I'm using sphinx to generate my doc as `html`, now i want to add a `pdf` format.

To generate my doc i'm using `python setup.py build_sphinx` and i want to keep using it.

I'v installed the `rst2pdf`, added all the needed parameters to my `conf.py` file and added to the `make` file the following:

```
if  "%1" == "pdf" (
    %SPHINXBUILD% -b pdf %ALLSPHINXOPTS% %BUILDDIR%/pdf
    echo.
 echo.Build finished. The PDF files are in %BUILDDIR%/pdf
    goto end
)
```

All as said at [here](http://thyagjs.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/create-pdf-document-from-your-sphinx.html), Now the convention is to use `make pdf`

**Question:**

How can i integrate `make pdf` inside my `setup.cfg` so it can integrate with `python setup.py build_sphinx`?